# Scroll one line of text while another line is static on a SSD1306 OLED

Tags: esp8266, ssd1306

I have an SSD1306 OLED that I have connected to a Wemos D1 Mini. It works like a charm, but I was wondering if it was possible to have two lines of code, where one line is static, and the other one scrolls? No example on the web as far as I have tried to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer on the following site: https://lastminuteengineers.com/oled-display-arduino-tutorial/

Basically, the method `startscroll*` on the display takes some arguments.
By passing the proper start page and stope page you can scroll parts of the screen.

[Refer to OLED Memory Map](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/microview-hookup-guide/oled-memory-map) for explanation of the pages on the screen. There are eight pages in the display from 0 to 7, so we can scroll a certain part of the screen by passing specific page numbers as parameters.

In this example, we pass both the parameters as 0x00. This will scoll the first page only (first 8 rows) of the display:

```
// Scroll part of the screen
display.setCursor(0,0);
display.setTextSize(1);
display.println("Scroll");
display.println("some part");
display.println("of the screen.");
display.display();
display.startscrollright(0x00, 0x00);
```

Source: https://lastminuteengineers.com/oled-display-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: Please either explain more about the solution in your answer or delete your question. These Q&A are supposed to serve as knowledgebase and links tend to get broken rather fast, which would make your answer completely useless for others

Comment: @chrisl Updated my post. Thanks for telling me, you are completely right.